# Different types using pipe operator in dart

Tags: typescript, dart

I've encountered a minor problem in dart. I want my parameter to accept a list with 3 different types. In typescript Id use a pipe operator:

```
public x(...parameters: (FirstType | SecondType | ThirdType)[])
```

How would I go on about doing this in dart?

Comment: Dart doesn't have union types like this. One possible workaround is If `FirstType`, `SecondType`, and `ThirdType` all extend a common base class, then you can use a generic type that is restricted to types that extend the base class. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#restricting-the-parameterized-type

Comment: See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1222 and https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/83.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass a list of different type elements as an argument in dart

```dart
void main() {
  List<dynamic> manyTypes = ['test', 15, 17.8, true];
  print(testFunction(manyTypes));
}
dynamic testFunction (List<dynamic> a) => a;
```

You can have as much types as you want when using the dynamic keyword declaration even other types that yo made yourself

you can also achieve the same result with this code

```dart
void main() {
  dynamic manyTypes = ['test', 15, 17.8, true];
  print(testFunction(manyTypes));
}
dynamic testFunction (dynamic a) => a;
```

Comment: This seems like it would accept any type, is there any way to just accept those three specific types?

Comment: In that case I would use this method as a workaround

```dart
void main() {
  List<dynamic> manyTypes = <dynamic>[
    <int>[18, 22, 0, 1],
    <bool>[true, false],
    <String>['hello', 'world', '!']
  ];
  print(testFunction(manyTypes));
}
dynamic testFunction (dynamic a) => a; 
```
But then you'd have to access each type sub list in order to use those values